# Flash/PHP: Using the AS3 Jpeg Encoder

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, jpeg, encoder

I am a beginner at both Actionscript3 and PHP, and I'm trying to get Henry Jone's movie clip to jpeg code to work for me, as seen here:

http://henryjones.us/articles/using-the-as3-jpeg-encoder

I downloaded the source and then uploaded the .swf and the .php in the same directory. However, when I click "download your sketch," it downloads the .php file instead of a jpeg.

The .swf I uploaded can be seen here:

http://www.snut.org/storage/scrntest/sketch.swf

I didn't change any of the code from the source I downloaded, so I can't figure our what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: If the php file is downloaded instead of executed, it sound like your web server is not configured to run PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb - any time your web server downloads .php files instead of rendering the output of the file it is a good sign that your server isn't set up to handle PHP. You need to tell Apache to use PHP, google around for "install PHP on Apache web server" and that should get you started.

Basically .php files are just text files, so unless you have something telling your web server to treat .php files different from normal text files then it'll just assume the user wants to download the file that's being linked.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that was the problem, but you're exactly right. I tried uploading it on a different server that supports PHP and it worked. Thanks!